# Allow specific REST point without authentication

Tags: authentication, spring-boot

I'd like to allow only one specific Rest point to be accessed without authentication.

Controller:

@GetMapping( MYPATH + "/{id}")
public Info getInfoById(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("id") String id) throws Exception {
...
}

@GetMapping( MYPATH + "/{name}")
public Info getInfoByName(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("name") String name) throws Exception {
...
}

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers( Controller.MYPATH + "/**");
}
```

}

I can disable authentication for both points if I leave antMatchers as shown above.  But my goal is to allow only the GET with the id parameter thru without authentication.  I tried Controller.MYPATH + "?id=**", but it does not work.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming a `name` doesn't include numbers, use a pattern similar to [A-Za-z+] in your ant pattern (the string fed into antMatchers()).

Comment: Actually, it could contain numbers. Thanks, though.

Comment: How about your ids? Are they made of digits only? Is there no pattern to tell the difference between ids and names?

Comment: The ids are guids, the names better not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone cares, the solution was to create multiple beans and load them with different profiles i.e. @Profile("blah-unauthenticated").  This way I kept all authenticated/unauthenticated points under different profiles.